# 301 redirect not working (server fault)

Tags: redirect

I'm a beguinner and I don't know much about web programming and different ways to do redirect.

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect from an old site to a new site, for seo purpose. My problem is that the old site is not hosted on regular hosting, but on http://pages.videotron.com/duclosma/controlemd.html .

Therefor, regular 301 redirect with the .htaccess doesn't seem to work.

Do you guys have any solution on how to do a proper redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Show the htaccess file your attempting to use what are the conditions you are trying?
Also as an alternative though won't give you the code for 301/302 is the good ol fashion meta based refresh assuming you have access to the html file above.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://mynewsite.com/">
```

Also theres other concepts if you have access to the files on the server where the original page was hosted. You could if you have access to the files, is delete them from the server drop a htaccess that acts as a catch-all redirects everything to a php file, where the php file redirects with headers in it similar to how Wordpress handles its htaccess. All in all though it depends on what rights you have over the location of that hosted old site. As you need to make sure any htaccess, or anything else you put is on the same server that its on to redirect to the new server.

***EDIT***

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourolddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yournewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, I have access to the whole ftp of the old site, but nothing else.

Comment: As for the .htaccess, it contained the following code : Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Any idea what would be the best thing for me then? And how to do it? Considering good seo. Thanks a lot.

Comment: edited my initial post, your rewrite rule shown here doesn't have a condition from the looks of it. Note that this has to reside on the same server as the old site in order to work, sounds like you may be attempting to put it on the new server, which won't work. htaccess tells the server someone is currently accessing a site for to apply different rules accordingly. Its overriding the default usage of the server

Answer (score 0):

You could do a Javascript redirect.
At the top of the page(s) You want to redirect.

window.location = "http://yournewsite.com";